# Gradle `java-platform` plugin: How to set dependencies dynamic version resolution?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, maven-bom

I am trying to make BOM (Bill of materials POM) using Gradle's `java-platform` plugin and wish to use Gradle's locking feature alongside with that plugin: I want to keep versions always up-to-date.

This is part of my `build.gradle` file.

```
plugins {
   id "java-platform"
   id "maven-publish"
}

javaPlatform {
  allowDependencies()
}

dependencyLocking {
  lockAllConfigurations()
  lockMode = LockMode.STRICT
}

... skipped ...

dependencies {
  constraints {
    api("com.graphql-java:graphql-java:${library_graphql_version}")
    api("com.graphql-java:java-dataloader:${library_graphqlDataloader_version}")
    
    // Redisson
    api("org.redisson:redisson-hibernate-53:${library_redisson_version}")
    api("org.redisson:redisson-spring-boot-starter:${library_redisson_version}")
    api("org.redisson:redisson-spring-data-23:${library_redisson_version}")
  }
}

publications {
  some(MavenPublication) {
    from components.javaPlatform
    afterEvaluate {
      pom {
        name = 'BOM'
        description = 'Bill of Materials (BOM)'
      }
    }
  }
}

... skipped ...
```

`gradle.properties` file

```
library_graphql_version=14.+
library_graphqlDataloader_version=2.+
library_redisson_version=3.+
```

And when I execute `generatePomFileForSomePublication` task it is translated to the following POM fragment:

```
... skipped ...

<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
        <version>14.+</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-dataloader</artifactId>
        <version>2.+</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson-hibernate-53</artifactId>
        <version>3.+</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.+</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson-spring-data-23</artifactId>
        <version>3.+</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

... skipped ...
```

Obviously, there are `plus` signs that shouldn't be in resulting POM. It means, that dependency resolution doesn't work for `java-platform` constraints.

So the question is how can I make that dependency resolution work for these `constraints`?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround w/o using `java-platform` plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
  google()
  gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencyLocking {
  lockAllConfigurations()
  lockMode = LockMode.STRICT
}

configurations {
  all {
    resolutionStrategy.activateDependencyLocking()
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, "minutes"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile("com.graphql-java:graphql-java:${library_graphql_version}")
  compile("com.graphql-java:java-dataloader:${library_graphqlDataloader_version}")
  
  compile("org.redisson:redisson-hibernate-53:${library_redisson_version}")
  compile("org.redisson:redisson-spring-boot-starter:${library_redisson_version}")
  compile("org.redisson:redisson-spring-data-23:${library_redisson_version}")
}

jar {
  enabled = false
}

publishing {
  publications {
    some(MavenPublication) {
      afterEvaluate {
        pom {
          name = 'BOM'
          description = 'Bill of Materials (BOM)'
          packaging = 'pom'
          
          withXml {
            Node pomNode = asNode() as Node
            pomNode.dependencyManagement.dependencies.each { dependencies ->
              pomNode.dependencies.dependency.each { node ->
                dependencies.append(node)
              }
            }
            pomNode.properties.each { properties ->
              pomNode.dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.each { dependency ->
                def groupId = dependency.groupId[0].value().first()
                def artifactId = dependency.artifactId[0].value().first()
                def version = dependency.version[0].value().first()
                
                def propertyName = "${groupId}.${artifactId}.version"
                properties.append(new Node(null, propertyName, null, version))
  
                dependency.version[0].setValue("\${${propertyName}}")
              }
            }
            pomNode.remove(pomNode.dependencies)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```